# CodeIgniter File upload not working and not giving error

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

I am trying upload file from CodeIgniter. File not giving any error and even not storing file in uploads folder whic is in root directory or codeigniter. Can somebody help ? Please note as i already gave 755 permission to my uploads folder. below is my code

view file

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $error;?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('UploadController');?>

<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is my controller

```
<?php

class UploadController extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('uploadview', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }

    function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload("add_1"))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->view('uploadview', $data);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

please help me in this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some mistakes in your code:
Please changes on following lines:

1.change 
     `form_open_multipart('UploadController')`
  **to**
    `form_open_multipart('UploadController/do_upload')`

2.change 
  `$this->upload->do_upload("add_1")`
  **to** 
 `$this->upload->do_upload("userfile")`.
3.change
`$this->load->view('upload_form', $error);`
  **to**
   `$this->load->view('uploadview', $error);`

Answer (score 0):

change

```
form_open_multipart('UploadController')
```

to

```
form_open_multipart('UploadController/do_upload')
```

Answer (score 0):

change your form action path

form_open_multipart('UploadController/do_upload')

or you can use it like this in one method:

```
function index()
{
    $config['upload_path']      = 'upload_path';
  $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
  $config['max_size']         = 5120;
  $config['encrypt_name']     = true;

  $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('image', 'lang:image', 'file_size_max[5M]|file_allowed_type[image]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('uploadview', array('error' => ' ' ))
    }
    else
    {
        $user = array();

        $uploaded  = $this->upload->do_upload('add_1');

    //delete the original file if another is uploaded
    if($uploaded)
    {           
      $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

      $this->load->view('uploadview', $data);
    } else {
      $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

      $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    }
}
```

And make sure your upload path is right.